# throw err; ^ error: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql

my database name is node_loginn and it does have a users table in it. When I try to compile the code I'm getting the below error.

" /Users/simar/Desktop/node_login /server.js:80
throw err;
^

error: relation "users" does not exist
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/simar/Desktop/node_login /node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98) "

```
.env file 

DB_USER=conbailey
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=nodeloginn
```

```
dbConfig.js file 

require("dotenv").config();
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`;

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionsString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString

});

module.exports = { pool };
```

```
server.js file 


        pool.query(
            `SELECT * FROM users
            WHERE email = $1`,
            [email],
            (err, res) => {

                if (err) {
                    throw err;

                }
                console.log(res.rows);

                if(res.rows.length > 0){
                    errors.push({ message: "email already exists"});
                    res.render("register",{errors});
                }
                               
            }
        );



    }

});
```

Comment: please check 2 things 1. whether table `users` is in public schema, if not then use `schemaname.tablename` 2. when table name is in small case, if not then use correct case surrounded by double quotes

Comment: "*it does have a users table in it*" - how do you know? How did you create the table? Can you access the table in some other tool than through the `pg` node library?